# Firebase Hosting deploys CRA app to 'build' subdirectory

Tags: firebase, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

### What is happening

When I execute `firebase deploy --only hosting` given the below folder structure, it deploys the entirety of the `ui` folder.  Meaning, I will have to visit my app at `http://my-app.web.app/build`.

### What I would like to happen

I want to deploy the contents of the `build` folder generated in the `predeploy` step of `firebase.json` as the root of the application. So that `my-app/ui/build/index.html` ultimately winds up as `http://my-app.web.app`.

### What else have I tried

I thought it would work if I specified `"public": "ui/build"` in `firebase.json`, but what happens then is the following error about `ui/build/package.json` not being found.

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\me\Projects\my-app\ui\build\package.json'
```

I understand it's looking for `ui/build/package.json` because of `public: ui/build` but how can I tell it to build  from the `ui` folder, but deploy the resulting `build` folder?

### folder structure

- my-app

  - functions/
  - ui/

    - build (after `npm run build`, at least)
    - src/

      - whatever.tsx
  - .firebaserc
  - firebase.json
  - firestore.indexes.json
  - firestore.rules

### firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],



    // this is the problem line
    "public": "ui",



    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oof!  Couldn't see it through the trees.

I simply divorced the `predeploy` script from the `public` setting in `firebase.json`:

Set the pre-deploy to target the ui folder ( because `$RESOURCE_DIR` will become `ui/build`) and set the `public` value to `ui/build`:

```
"hosting": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ui run build"
    ],
    "public": "ui/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```